# I'm coding a linked list in JS and a prepend function that I wrote is not working how I intended

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list

So my initial code looks like this:

```
class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = new Node(-1);
    this.tail = this.head;
  };
  prepend(value) {
    let next = this.head.nextNode;
    this.head = new Node(value);
    this.head.nextNode = next;
  };
};

class Node {
  constructor(value, nextNode = null) {
    this.value = value;
    this.nextNode = nextNode;
  };
};
```

Let's say I were to prepend a value of 1, and then prepend another value of 2. The output would look something like this:

```
LinkedList = {
  head: {
    nextNode: null,
    value: 2
  },
  tail: {
    nextNode: null,
    value: -1
  }
};
```

This isn't really what I intended. I instead want the head's value to equal 2, and then for the head to point to a new node with a value of 1.

I'm quite lost on how to fix this, and I didn't want to just look up the answer since I'm trying to learn how to implement something like this on my own after learning the concept for the first time. I'd be grateful for any help I can get. I would prefer if you could give me a hint to nudge me in the right direction, and then put the correct way to fix this below that, as I'm still set on figuring this out without looking up the answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change `let next = this.head.nextNode;` (initially `null`) to `let next = this.head` (initially `Node(-1)`).

Comment: Thanks, that literally fixed the issue as simply as possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use some fake node for an empty list you should clear it before adding real nodes.

For the next node you should take `this.head` instead of `this.head.nextNode` (initially null).

Also you don't use Node's constructor's second parameter - pass the next node directly to the constructor:

```js
class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.tail = this.head = new Node(-1);
  };
  prepend(value) {
    if(this.head.value === -1 && this.head.nextNode === null){ // an empty list, delete the head and tail
      delete this.head, delete this.tail;
    }
    this.head = new Node(value, this.head); // leverage the Node's constructor to pass the next node
    this.tail ??= this.head; // set the tail on the first node
  };
};

class Node {
  constructor(value, nextNode = null) {
    this.value = value;
    this.nextNode = nextNode;
  };
};

const list = new LinkedList;

list.prepend(1);
list.prepend(2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(list, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

I suggest to change `-1` to a symbol:

```js
class LinkedList {
  static EMPTY_NODE = Symbol();
  constructor() {
    this.tail = this.head = new Node(LinkedList.EMPTY_NODE);
  };
  prepend(value) {
    if(this.head.value === LinkedList.EMPTY_NODE){
      delete this.head, delete this.tail;
    }
    this.head = new Node(value, this.head);
    this.tail ??= this.head;
  };
};

class Node {
  constructor(value, nextNode = null) {
    this.value = value;
    this.nextNode = nextNode;
  };
};

const list = new LinkedList;

list.prepend(1);
list.prepend(2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(list, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

But for an empty list I would prefer the head and tail being `null`:

```js
class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.tail = this.head = null;
  };
  prepend(value) {
    this.head = new Node(value, this.head);
    this.tail ??= this.head;
  };
};

class Node {
  constructor(value, nextNode = null) {
    this.value = value;
    this.nextNode = nextNode;
  };
};

const list = new LinkedList;

list.prepend(1);
list.prepend(2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(list, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I'm not coding this in TypeScript, this is vanilla JS.

Comment: @mehkij you can easily add TypeScript yourself. TS isn't not related to logic.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit confused. I thought "static" was a TS thing, not a vanilla JS thing, and I was saying that I'm coding this in vanilla JS, not TS (I'm a beginner so go easy on me lol).

Comment: @mehkij oops, some misunderstanding, yes, it's in vanilla JS